# Symbian character printing

Tags: c++, symbian, char, descriptor

I am attempting to construct a very simple proof of concept that I can write a web service and actually call the service from a symbian environment. The service is a simple Hello service which takes a name in the form of a const char* and returns back a greeting of the form "hello " + name in the form of a char*. My question is, how do I convert a char* to a TPtrC16 so that I can use the console->Write function to print out the response to screen? I know I could search through the API and figure this out, but for a basic conceptual demo I'd rather not spend the time (not sure that Symbian is something I will ever work with again).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `const char*` string is in US-ASCII, you can use `TDes::Copy` to copy it wrapped in a `TPtrC8` to a 16-bit descriptor:

```
const char *who = "world";
TBuf<128> buf;
buf.Copy(TPtrC8((TText8*)who));
console->Printf(_L("hello %S\n"), &buf);
```

If it is in some other encoding, have a look at the `charconv` API in the SDK help.

Comment: There were a few things I had to fiddle with in order to get this to work. In the end the code looks like this:
  char *who = "world";
  TUint8 *i((unsigned char*)who);
  TBuf<128> buf;
  buf.Copy(TPtrC8(i));
  console->Printf(_L("hello %S\n"), &buf);

I can probably refactor some of this to make it prettier, but it works for now. Thanks for the help!